# Auto increment pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to auto increment a field in my mongo collection. The field is an 'id' field and it contains the 'id' of each document. For example. 1, 2, 3 etc.

What I want to happen is insert a new document and take the 'id' from the last document and add 1 to it so that the new document is lastID + 1.

The way I have written the code makes it so that it gets the last document and adds 1 to the last document and then updates it. So if the last id is 5, then the new document will have 5 and the document that I was incrementing on now has the new 'id' of 6.

I am not sure how to get round this so any help would be appreciated.

Code

```
last_id = pokemons.find_one({}, sort=[( 'id', -1)])

last_pokemon = pokemons.find_one_and_update({'id' : last_id['id']}, {'$inc': {'id': 1}}, sort=[( 'id', -1)]) 

new_pokemon = {
              "name" : name, "avg_spawns" : avg_spawns, "candy" : candy, "img" : img_link, "weaknesses" : [], "type" : [], "candy_count" : candy_count, 
              "egg" : egg, "height" : height, "multipliers" : [], "next_evolution" : [], "prev_evolution" : [],
              "spawn_chance" : spawn_chance, "spawn_time" : spawn_time, "weight" : weight, "id" : last_pokemon['id'], "num" : last_pokemon['id'],
}

pokemons.insert_one(new_pokemon)
```

The variables in new_pokemon don't matter as I am just having issues with the last_pokemon part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_one` command in MongoDB command doesn't support sort functionality. You have to make use of normal find command with limit parameter set to `1`.

```
last_id = pokemons.find({}, {"id": 1}, sort=[('id', -1)]).limit(1).next()  # Will error if there are no documents in collection due to the usage of `next()`

last_id["id"] += 1

new_pokemon = {
              "name" : name, "avg_spawns" : avg_spawns, "candy" : candy, "img" : img_link, "weaknesses" : [], "type" : [], "candy_count" : candy_count, 
              "egg" : egg, "height" : height, "multipliers" : [], "next_evolution" : [], "prev_evolution" : [],
              "spawn_chance" : spawn_chance, "spawn_time" : spawn_time, "weight" : weight, "id" : last_id['id'], "num" : last_id['id'],
}

pokemons.insert_one(new_pokemon)
```

Comment: I get the same outcome as my original way. The last in the collection will keep getting updated instead of assigning the new pokemon with the lastid + 1

Comment: @Darren_D19 sorry I misunderstood your question. I have updated the answer, kindly check if that is what you are looking for.